# Controlling music volume within app [iOS]

Tags: ios, audio, avplayer

I have a fully working audio player that uses `AVPlayer` to play music. I used `MPVolumeView` in order to control volume. But as an extra feature I wanted users to control volume in some situations with a settings pane, which doesn't require user to manually set volume via `MPVolumeView`.

At this point I am well aware that I cannot change value of `MPVolumeView`, therefore hardware volume without user being interacted with.

But I want to know is there a way I can change volume of currently playing track of `AVPLayer` or `AVPlayer` itself (example: keeping current hardware volume as the maximum volume value).

Can I accomplish this with `AVAudioPlayer`, `MPMusicPlayerController` if not with `AVPlayer` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

`[yourAVPlayer setVolume: 0.0]`,

Ranging from 0.0 through 1.0 (0.0 -> Muted , 1.0 -> Max Vol).

Then you can have multiple AVPlayer with differents volumes

(Sorry for my english :) )